# Change source of shortcut in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge excel which multiple different data sources.
Everyday I need to manually change the data source because the files are always like
xxx_2022_08_04.xlsx.
Now I was hoping to make a macro of all the data sources and than change them via vba.

I have the new source paths in my table but I can't figure out how to access the shortcut options and how to change the path of each.

So lets say I want to access shortcut 'Profit' which path .../xxx_2022_08_03.xlsx and change it too .../xxx_2022_08_04.xlsx.

How would I do this in vba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to call the *Edit Links* dialog box in order to replace the links in question. You will find this in the *Data* tab in the group *Queries and connection* or you use [ChangeLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.changelink)

```
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:= _
    "<Path>\xlfile", NewName:= _
    "<Path>\newxlfile", Type:= _
    xlExcelLinks
```